# Jest Unit Class with Dependencies

Tags: javascript, jestjs, mobx, babel-jest

I'm trying to unit test this class that has a dependency of `AppDB` and `createStudy` that I need to mock. To get started I'm attempting to unit test the simple method `startLoadingData` which happens to be a MobX `action`

```
import { observable, action } from 'mobx'
import { Intent } from '@blueprintjs/core'
import { createStudy } from '../database/DatabaseInit'
import { AppDB } from '../database/Database'


export default class UIStore {
  // ui state
  // booleans indicating open/close state of modals
  @observable createDialogue
  @observable importDialogue
  @observable revisionsDialogue
  @observable runDialogue
  // boolean indicating loading or waiting for async action
  @observable loadingData
  // array indicating navigation
  @observable breadcrumbs
  @observable processingMessages

  constructor(rootStore) {
    this.rootStore = rootStore
    this.breadcrumbs = []
    this.importDialogue = false
    this.createDialogue = false
    this.revisionsDialogue = false
    this.runDialogue = false
    // boolean to display loading blur on table that displays data
    this.loadingData = false
    // processing messages for import and other async loads
    this.processingMessages = []
  }
  @action startLoadingData() {
    this.loadingData = true
  }
}
```

My test file below is getting nowhere because there's an error being thrown related to a separate dependency of `sqlite3` in the `AppDB` and `createStudy` imports. My understanding is that if I mock those two dependencies that I can avoid the error because they'll be mocked and not real implementations trying to use `sqlite3`.

```
// UIStore domain store unit test
// import * as Database from '../../app/database/Database'
// import * as DatabaseInit from '../../app/database/DatabaseInit'
import UIStore from '../../app/stores/UIStore'


describe('UIStore', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    // jest.spyOn(Database, 'AppDB').andReturn('mockAppDB')
    // jest.spyOn(DatabaseInit, 'createStudy').andReturn('createStudy')
    jest.mock('../../app/database/Database')
    // jest.mock('DatabaseInit')
  })
  it('starts loading data', () => {
    const testUIStore = new UIStore(this)
    testUIStore.startLoadingData()
    expect(testUIStore.loadingData).toBe(true)
  })
})
```

As you can see, trying a bunch of things, but I don't seem to be getting anywhere. I've read about manual mocks, and thought that might be the case so I made a manual mock of `Database` but not even sure if I'm doing that correctly.

```
const Database = jest.genMockFromModule('../Database.js')

module.exports = Database
```

I dont think this matters, but it might be worth noting that `AppDB` is a ES6 class and `createStudy` is a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jest should [auto mock](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/manual-mocks.html) modules from `node_modules` if you create a `__mocks__` folder in your root project folder and create in that folder mocks for the modules you want auto mocked. By auto mock I mean that when writing a test and Jest detects that folder it will automatically load the mock instead of the original module. This also applies to dependencies of dependencies.

So in your case I would try to create a `sqlite3` like so:

```
/project
|
-> __mocks__
|  |
|  -> sqlite3/index.js <- export mocked functions
|
-> node_modules
```

At least this is how I deal with libraries in my Jest tests.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have implemented that file structure with the following code:

`const sqlite3 = jest.genMockFromModule('sqlite3');
module.exports = sqlite3;
`

Basically, there are no specific methods I need mocked, I just don't want it to look in the actual `sqlite3` node module because due to my project environment (Electron) it's incompatible with Jest (Node).

However, it appears even with this mock, the actual `sqlite3` module is still being referenced.

Comment: It appears I've solved my own problem that was originating due to the two `package.json` structure of my electron app, and that the `node_modules` in my `app` directory did not have the binding for node that was in my root directory. A simple copy of the binding removed the error I was getting, and eliminating my theory that I should simply mock the library. Sorry that the question was actually more specific than it appeared. But, I think in principal, your answer makes sense according to everything else I've read about Jest.